# Google App Engine optional slash redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, slash

I have a java app running on Google App Engine...  I'd like to make the trailing slash optional for directories... so navigating to www.domain.com/test and www.domain.com/test/ would yield the same thing.

How do I achieve that?

I know about the app.yaml configuration file but I am running a Java app not python..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/QTVjd9uDiXI). Works for me, though looks like a hack. I think it worth posting issue to google, as thee servlet specification requires adding trailing slashes when attempting to find a proper welcome-file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a [filter](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Servlet_Filters/) that intercepts requests and appends the forward slash if necessary. Generally it's better to send a redirect rather than serving the same content, so you don't end up with two canonical URLs for everything, and all your contents indexed twice.

What constitutes a 'directory' depends on your application, of course, and there's no hard and fast rule for figuring that out.